# Incentive to recruit B2B customers for generative interviews

Tags: user-research, customer-experience, b2b, user-interviews, recruitment

Together with my team need to recruit participants to run some generative interviews, 15 in total. We have a customer base, but we're not sure if we should offer them an incentive and what kind could be. The relationship between this segment of users (businesses from small to large sizes) and our company, happens mostly through customer assistants, so this will be our first approach to them as part of the UXR team. We have some budget but it is not too much, so it would be nice to hear any suggestions or a similar experience. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your customer assistants have relationships with the customers (vs. just ticket-based issue resolution), I would start by reaching out to them, describe the project, and ask if they can help connect you with customers who might be especially interested in solving the specific problem you're working on. If they can help you set up the interviews, that's even better, because it will look to the customer like they're going above and beyond to help them. Usually in that case, no incentive is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The main incentive is being part of the SASS creation process and helping create a product that will eventually help deliver more value to the community of customers. Also, early access to new product concepts, user interfaces, and sneak previews of upcoming roadmap items.
finally, you can add that you will give them an Amazon gift card. but that shouldn't be the main incentive